# How to convert slightly different tables?

Tags: java, hibernate, orm

Is there a way to convert table entries from an old table to a new one using the same entity class?

To be specfic, here are my entity class' annotations for the new table:

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Basic(optional = false)
@Column(name = "benutzer_id")
private Integer benutzerId;
@Basic(optional = false)
@Column(name = "benutzer_name")
private String benutzerName;
@Column(name = "benutzer_vorname")
private String benutzerVorname;
@Column(name = "benutzer_nachname")
private String benutzerNachname;
@JoinColumn(name = "gruppe_id", referencedColumnName = "gruppe_id")
@ManyToOne(optional = false)
private Gruppe gruppe;
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "benutzer")
private Collection<Bestellung> bestellungen;
```

The columns "benutzer_vorname" and "benutzer_nachname" are missing in the old table, so Hibernate crashes, if it tries to map the table entries.

Do I have to create a new entity class or is it possible to convert the data using the existing one?

Comment: But... Is the old table going to stay? Do you need to use JPA for the "conversion"?

Comment: No it isn't going to stay. I'd prefer using JPA because it's easier to code.

Comment: Using JPA is fine... but not for that task. Why don't you use a raw sQL script to migrate the data from the old table to the new one? That would be the best tool for the job. Am I missing something?

Comment: I have to write some sort of converter tool using JPA, so I was interested in doing this using one entity class. It seems I have to fetch each table entry via SQL. Thanks though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Do I have to create a new entity class or is it possible to convert the data using the existing one?

You can't map an entity on two tables (I'm not talking about the JOIN inheritance strategy here) so you'll have to create a new entity.

Answer (score 1):

If you're considering how to migrate from one table structure to another, then Hibernate may not be the best solution.

If the table is flat (no associations) then it might be really simple to copy the entries across using SQL. You can just select the required data and insert it directly into the new table (syntax probably varies by DBMS though, which could be a problem for you).

In standard SQL you can do this as follows

```
INSERT INTO new_table (
    column1, 
    column2, 
    column3
)
SELECT
    column1 as "Copied value for new entity",
    'a default' as "Default value for new entity",
    some_column * 3 as "Computed Value for new entity"
FROM 
    new_table;
```

Select column aliases are optional of course, I've just used them as comments for the various things you can do.

Of course if you have a more complicated table structure that you'd like to flatten you can perform a query of any complexity as long as it returns a set of rows you'd like to insert.

Comment: The problem is I have to "migrate" many times for testing purposes.

Comment: You can have hibernate run SQL through the datasource that you have configured it with. Just use `session.createSQLQuery( "SELECT... " ).list();` instead.